# Is there any significance of returning a promise in a controller in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

If invoking an asynchronous function in any controller, then what is the difference between two following routes:

```
router.post('/proxy/notify', function (req, res) {
    res.send("ok");
    postOptions.uri = req.body.uri;
    delete req.body.uri;
    postOptions.form = req.body;
    return request(postOptions).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
});
```

Now, even if I skip the return in the last line it still works:

```
router.post('/proxy/notify', function (req, res) {
    res.send("ok");
    postOptions.uri = req.body.uri;
    delete req.body.uri;
    postOptions.form = req.body;
    request(postOptions).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
});
```

The only advantage that I can see is that return will ensure no line is executed after the `request()` function call if any.

Comment: The return value of the callback is irrelevant, all that matters is what happens inside, so you're right, that is the only function it serves.

Comment: @AllTheTime How about resource deallocation? Couldn't it happen that if Node gets a promise returned from a callback it waits until the callback resolves before destroying the allocated resources (db handles, file handles shouldn't rely on garbage collection)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use promise aware middleware assuming this is `express` you're using then no. There is currently no significance.

That said, express might use it in the future.

Comment: Koa2 uses async/await in middleware hence is promise aware, what difference will it make?

Comment: async/await aware middleware is a completely different story, you can `return` the response instead of calling a function like `res.send`.